# Rangeslider.js | Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, rangeslider

I'm trying to use rangeslider.js

This is my HTML includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rangeslider.js-2.1.1/rangeslider.min.js"></script>
```

This is my HTML:

```
<input type="range" min="0.0" max="1.0" step="0.05" value="0.8" data-rangeslider="" style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0;">

<script>
    // Initialize a new plugin instance for all
    // e.g. $('input[type="range"]') elements.
    $('input[type="range"]').rangeslider();

    // Destroy all plugin instances created from the
    // e.g. $('input[type="range"]') elements.
    $('input[type="range"]').rangeslider('destroy');

    // Update all rangeslider instances for all
    // e.g. $('input[type="range"]') elements.
    // Usefull if you changed some attributes e.g. `min` or `max` etc.
    $('input[type="range"]').rangeslider('update', true);
</script>
```

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.
```

These are the lines that appear to be being referencing to in `rangeslider.min.js`:

```
line 169: this.handleDimension = g(this.$handle[0], "offset" + i(this.DIMENSION)),

line 272: "string" == typeof b && e[b].apply(e, c)
```

I am unsure as to what type error I am causing?

Comment: Any luck with that? I am getting the exact same error

Comment: same problem here, It seems to be the update function

Comment: I had the same problem with no solution

Comment: after calling destroy, re initialize then update, destroy removes your range slider so you should not be able to update after that

Comment: try $('input[type="range"]').rangeSlider().rangeslider('update', true);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to include the css file of `rangeslider.js`, and you shouldn't destroy the rangeslider.

For a minimun example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.2/rangeslider.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="range" min="10" max="1000" step="10" value="300">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.2/rangeslider.js"></script>
    <script>
       $('input[type="range"]').rangeslider({polyfill: false});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The example above is based on the code in [rangeslider.js](http://rangeslider.js.org/).

I think the **Usage** section in [rangeslider.js](http://rangeslider.js.org/) is just a script showcase. So if we directly use those scripts, the following errors occurs:

Error message in chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Error message in Firefox:

> TypeError: this.$handle is undefined

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. The script to initialize the range slider input is being initialized before the DOM renders. Try writing your script tag like this

```js
<script>
$(function() {
    // Code here
});
</script>
```